# How to get list of all azure web sites using RESTful API

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

The following RESTful endpoint lists all sites under South East Asia web-space:

https://management.core.windows.net/**subscription-id**/services/webspaces/**SoutheastAsiawebspace**/sites

I want to get a list of all sites across **all** web-spaces. Is there a REST API for that?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that get the list of all webspaces first and then enumerate every webspace to get a list of sites underneath that...

I also recommend that instead of using the OLD Rest API for service management, you use the new ARM API's to get the list of sites. You can use the https://resources.azure.com/ tool to understand the hierarchy of API's and when expand the nodes in side this tool, it will show you how the exact REST API call should look like.

Hope this helps !!!

Comment: I am already iterating over webspaces, but wanted a straightforward API like one for listing cloud-services. Also, what does OLD mean? Are these deprecated? I checked on MSDN and they seemed latest. Also, I couldn't get resources.azure.com to work for me. Is there a documentation for this site?

Comment: I don't think there is a straightforward API to get all sites....

I am not sure if the existing API's are getting deprecated but ARM API's is the new recommended way of accessing service management information.

You can read more documentation on these API at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn758095.aspx

 I am not sure why http://resources.azure.com is not working for you. Are you getting some error or you not able to login to that tool (hoping that you are trying IE to browse it...)

Comment: Check out http://blog.davidebbo.com/2015/01/azure-resource-manager-client.html as well